# Only variables should be passed by reference - when using LIMIT with bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, slim

I want use `LIMIT` with `bindParam` so I build this query:

```
$app->get('/contact/get_contacts/{contact_number}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contact LIMIT :contact_number";
    $sql->bindParam("contact_number", intval($args["contact_number"]), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->fetchAll();
    return $response->withJson($result);
});
```

I get this notice:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

What I did wrong? I'm using `Slim Framework` with `PDO`

Comment: The second parameter of bindParam should be an existing variable, not a result of a function. Store results in a variable and then use them when needed.

Comment: @vuryss thanks now working, but why I can't do this directly?

Comment: Just remove `intval`.

Comment: Because the function needs to store a result somewhere. The return value of a method is not a place where you can store value. You are trying to store a value in the response of intval, which is invalid action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:

```
$sql->bindParam("contact_number", intval($args["contact_number"]), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

with,

```
$sql->bindParam(":contact_number", $args["contact_number"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

- I have added the missing `:` before the parameter name.
- I have removed the `intval` function call, if you still want to use the function then use it outside of the `bindParam` function call.

As per the function definition:

```
public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )
```

the bound parameter is a [variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (`&$variable`).

**Reading Material**

[`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are double working on data type. You don't need `intval` while explicitly specified  `PDO::PARAM_INT`. Just remove `intval` or to see the reason go with [`bindValue`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

```
$sql->bindValue(":contact_number", intval($args["contact_number"]));
```